# Split SQL statements blocks using Regular expression in C#

Tags: sql, regex

Can we write an regular expression such that it splits the stored procedure in multiple SQL statements. 
It should split update, delete select etc statements.

Edit: my attempt to solve the problem http://tsqlparsergdr.codeplex.com/

Comment: created a small regex based application, gets my work done. Thanks for you comments

Answer (score 2):

If you have the grammar for the stored procedure language you could use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) so parse the procedure to get the relevant parts of the language out and the do any further processing necessary. It should be reletively easy to get a grammar going from scratch as well.

There would need to be a set of regex expressions to deal with the whole procedure. I.e. a regex to mach just insert statements that possible spans many lines and possible has local variables from the proc in it and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with a known set of SQL procedures it should be pretty easy to examine them and come up with a set of regexes to split them as required.

If you are looking for something which will handle any possible set of SQL procedures then regexes wont hack it! SQL has a complex recursive grammer, and, there will always be some sub select, group by, or literal that will break your regex based parser.

As the previous poster recommended you really need a full parser such as can be generated by ANTLR or Javacc (is there a C# eqivalent?).

There are a number of SQL-92 grammer definitions available for these parser generators on the net so a large part of the work has been done for you - the remaining part - writing the parsers application logic - is still far from trivial.

Answer (score 1):

To parse arbitrary stored procedures, you're far better off with a SQL parser.  Trying to parse arbitrary SQL with regexes will amount to writing your own parser.

To parse a specific set of stored procedures, a regex may be able to do the job.  You'll need to provide a few examples of the input you have and the desired output if you want a more detailed answer.